# Calculating Max Loan Amount based on Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula that calculates the maximum loan/line amount that a borrower qualifies for based on some criteria. The formula works fine but I would like to add a maximum limit based on another formula

This is the formula I currently have that calculates properly the maximum loan/line amount:

```
=IFERROR(IF(G15>G14,"",PV(G12/12,240,G13-((C19+G13)-(C20*G14)))*-1)-1,"")
```

I want to add functionality to cap the maximum line/loan amount at 90% of the value minus 1st mortgage balance, so the formula that I need to act as a cap is (C9*90%)-C10.

Can someone help me figure this out?

[image]

Comment: So why aren't you using `(C9*90%)-C10` I think I'm missing something...

Comment: I need to incorporate that formula into this one: =IFERROR(IF(G15>G14,"",PV(G12/12,240,G13-((C19+G13)-(C20G14)))-1)-1,"")

Comment: What is meant by `C20G14`?

Comment: Can you not wrap it in a MIN? e.g. `MIN( C9*90% - C10, big calculation )`  This forms a cap.

Comment: Is that long formula currently in `C9`? if yes, you could use `=(IFERROR(IF(G15>G14,"",PV(G12/12,240,G13-((C19+G13)-(C20G14)))-1)-1,"")*90%)-C10`

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the help of another forum using this formula: =MIN(IFERROR(IF(G15>G14,"",PV(G12/12,240,G13-((C19+G13)-(C20*G14)))*-1)-1,""), (C9*90%-C10))

Answer (score 1):

This formula worked:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(IF(G15>G14,"",PV(G12/12,240,
G13-((C19+G13)-(C20*G14)))*-1)-1,""), (C9*90%-C10))
```